# How to do multivariate regression of data in array in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

## Background

### What I want to achieve

I have some handy lookup tables that I want to find a formula for, so that I can plug in arbitrary numbers between the ones the table lists, and get serviceable results.

### What I've got so far

The lookup tables I've got follow the following format:

```
|ys\xs|-| 1 | 2 | 3 |  4 |...|
|-----|-|---|---|---|----|---|
|   5 |-| 40|150|350| 630|...|
|  10 |-| 50|210|460| 820|...|
|  15 |-| 60|240|530| 940|...|
|  20 |-| 65|260|580|1020|...|
| ... |-|...|...|...|....|...|
```

This maps each x and y value pair to a given value. For instance if you look up x = 2 and y = 10 you would get 210. However it is kinda difficult to figure out a decent value if you actually had say x = 3.6 and y = 17.

I've transcribed a couple of the tables to Google Sheets, trying to follow the same matrix/array format (to not make the transition from paper easier to follow):

```
|     | 1 | 2 | 3 |  4 |...|
|   5 | 40|150|350| 630|...|
|  10 | 50|210|460| 820|...|
|  15 | 60|240|530| 940|...|
|  20 | 65|260|580|1020|...|
| ... |...|...|...|....|...|
```

After a bit of research I think that what I want is to do a multivariate regression/multiple regression, with the xs and ys as independent variables, and whatever is in the matrix is the set of known values for the bound variable.

(At this point I considered a few alternatives. Instead of asking [the statistics stack exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for help with re-invent the statistics wheel at the points I'd inevitably get stuck, or researching what the good people at [the Data Science stack exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) claim to be the best python packages to grind through a tiny dataset, I figured that maybe the problem had already been solved in the world of spreadsheets in a simple and accessible way. Which has lead to me posting the question here.)

For doing multivariate regressions in Google Sheets I further found that I could probably use the built in [`LINEST`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094249) or [`LOGEST`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094251) functions,and I got to the point where I got `LOGEST` to work by restructuring some of the data by hand to a list like this:

```
|results|xs|ys|
|-------|--|--|
|    40 | 1| 5|
|    50 | 1|10|
|    60 | 1|15|
|    65 | 1|20|
|    .. |..|..|
|   150 | 2| 5|
|   210 | 2|10|
|    .. |..|..|
```

And then putting it into `LOGEST` this way: `LOGEST(A3:A_n,B3:C_n)`.

### The challenges

Doing so yielded 3 numbers, lets say `a`, `b`, and `c`. But from here the documentation is somewhat terse (in the case of `LOGEST`, and not mentioned at all for multiple free variables for `LINEST`), so I'm uncertain whether they are supposed to be used like this `ln(result) = x * ln(a) + y * ln(b) + ln(c)`, or whether x and y should be swapped, or if I should do something completely else with the output.

Another challenge is that reformatting the first array to a table by hand as shown above was a lot of work, and I think there should be a better way to get the results given what I have. But my spreadsheet and searching skills are insufficient to get further at this point.

Finally I also suspect that the data grows exponentially from left to right but follows a [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution) from top to bottom, but haven't been able to figure out whether Google Sheets has a regression method to fit that kind of data well at all, or if experimenting with `LINEST` and `LOGEST` is the best I can do.

## The question

Given a set of data points in an array in Google Sheets and the associated input value pairs for each entry (as shown above), how do I do a regression to get a formula with 2 input variables that decently matches the known points?

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to build the regression, test it with linear and exponential regression and see what works best. Can you put a your data in a public worksheet so that I can create it for you?

Comment: Have you tried the GROWTH function?